# Spring MVC rest controller not invoked

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I am developing a spring rest controller. But, when I try to access the url (http://localhost:8080/customer-crm/api/customer) it doesn't work and gives 404 not found. But for the root "/" it works fine and gives the `index.jsp` page

Here is the `AppConfiguration.class`:

```
package com.customer.crm.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.customer.crm")
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

And the `HibernateConfiguration.class`:

```
package com.customer.crm.configuration;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.customer.crm.configuration" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.customer.crm.entity" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;        
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
       return txManager;
    }
}
```

And here is the `Index.class` Controller:

```
package com.customer.crm.rest;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.customer.crm.entity.Customer;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Index {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/customer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Customer getIndex() {
        System.out.println("executing in index controller");
        Customer customer = new Customer("Mike", "John", "mike.john@gmail.com");

        return customer;
    }

}
```

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.customer.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>customer-crm</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>customer-crm Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
        <joda-time.version>2.3</joda-time.version>
        <testng.version>6.9.4</testng.version>
        <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.187</h2.version>
        <dbunit.version>2.2</dbunit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jsr303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Joda-Time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson for REST JSON Support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>${dbunit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                        <warName>SpringHibernateExample</warName>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <finalName>SpringHibernateExample</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Even the message in `getIndex()` is not printed. I tried cleaning the project and cleaning the tomcat directory but nothing changed. Can anyone tell me where is the problem?

Comment: In controller, try changing `value` attribute for `path`, so `path = "/customer"`

Comment: @wdc path is not found, it gives error when I try to change it.

Comment: From what I'm seeing you have used "/" as the root of your application and I don't see any path named "/customer-crm". So for me it seems like your desired page is available under "localhost:8080/api/customer"

Comment: 'customer-crm' is the application context, I also tried "localhost:8080/api/customer" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh guys, I solved it. It was a typo for the `application.properties` file. It was named "application.properities". Sorry for your time and thank you!